# MySQL: using a derived table within a sub-query

Tags: mysql

I have a query which is similar to the following:

```
SELECT
    col1, col2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            col1, col2
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            (table1.col1 > 1)
    ) AS table1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            col1, col2
        FROM
            table1
        INNER JOIN
            table2
        ON
            (table1.col1 = table2.col2)
    ) AS table2
WHERE
    (some other clause)
```

I want to know if table1 in the second sub-query is the derived table from the first sub-query, or just the "raw" data from the original table1.

I know that I cannot reference table1 within an ON clause in the second sub-query, though declaring it with FROM or within an INNER JOIN appears to work, which leads me to suspect it is the original table, and not the derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query you posted, `table1` in the `FROM` clause in the second subquery refers to the actual table and not the aliased "derived table" from the first subquery.

Don't forget your `ON` clause (join condition) unless you want a Cartesian product.

Outside the parenthesis, in your `ON` clause or `WHERE` clause after `AS table2`, `table1` will refer to the aliased derived table.

Comment: I just corrected the code by swapping the WHERE for an ON.

Comment: thanks. It's a shame I can't reference the derived table, but I'm sure I'll find a way around it.